Mqtt web sockets initial state
I'm using Homebridge and everything connected is controlled by mqtt. So that's fine for everybody using a Mac or an iPhone, but I want to be able to controls things from a browser. Using websockets (Paho mqttws31.js) that is working fine.
The only thing is that on opening the page there is no information about the current state of things. It always starts with all buttons in the default state. As soon as I change anything either in the home app or by sending a command through an mqtt client, the page is updated. (But of course only for the item that was changed externally).
I know the mqtt broker discards all messages as soon as they are delivered, so that makes things difficult. And since javascript is browser side my http server has no knowledge of what was has been going on in mqtt.
Is there any way to get the initial state of the page correct after opening? Maybe a script running on the server that keeps track of every topic in an xml-file so I can read that file on opening the page and set things right?
Or am I missing something very obvious and can this be done in a simpler way?

one (naive) approach would be to use retained messages - depending on the volume of topics, this may not be a good idea

I have about 20 devices on WiFi (the rest is Zigbee). If I want to use retained messages I would have to re-program all the WiFi devices, most of which do not support OTA. Also, but I might be doing this wrong, the Paho javascript seems to listens to all messages. So I does not explicitly subscribe to a topic, therefore it does not make a difference if the messages are retained or not.

of course it makes a difference, if it didn't then you wouldn't have the issue ... given the fact that you can't re-program the devices, your idea of a script running on the server that keeps track of every topic in an xml-file seems to be the best option - or, a script that listens to the current MQTT non-retained messages and re-publishes them as retained messages under a different topic

Just published a couple of messages (turning on lights) with an mqtt client and the retain flag on. Opened the web page and everything is in default state. So I guess I must be using the Paho javascript wrong?

Possibly - hard to tell
